# Stopping SoundPlayer playback

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to create my own little Soundboard for playing WAV files.  Now the playback isn't a problem, but I want a way to stop playback if required.  I thought of a stop button, but did not know how to make that work.  So I thought of using a loop but it doesn't seem to work.  Just wondering if anyone can help me where I am going wrong or if this is just a fail way to do it, then if you can show me a better way that would be great.  :)

```
    private void button1Sound(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        int i = 0;
        SoundPlayer simpleSound = new SoundPlayer(@"file.wav");

        while (i == 0)
        {
            simpleSound.Play();
            i++;
        }

        if (i >= 1)
        {
            simpleSound.Stop();
        }
    }
```

I also thought of just doing an ELSE IF but that also didn't work.  I tried:

```
    private void button1Sound(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        int i = 0;
        SoundPlayer simpleSound = new SoundPlayer(@"file.wav");

        if (i == 0)
        {
            simpleSound.Play();
            i++;
        }
        else if (i > 1)
        {
            simpleSound.Stop();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why was I down voted?!  I was polite, showed that I have tried different things, just because I'm a noob doesn't mean I should get down voted.

Comment: Some folks are just jerks, you had a good question, and presented it well, don't worry. We were all noobs at some point.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for reaffirming that.  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you've added `int i = 0` inside the void, every time the event is called, `i` will always be **0**. So it's better to include `i` outside the void.

```
 int i = 0;
 SoundPlayer simpleSound = new SoundPlayer(@"file.wav"); //Thanks to @Wanabrutbeer

 private void button1Sound(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {


        if (i == 0)
        {
            simpleSound.Play();
            i++;
        }

       else if (i >= 1)
        {
            simpleSound.Stop();
            i--;
        }
    }
```

**NOTICE**: The class `SoundPlayer` only plays **.wav** files. If you would like to play other media files such as **.mp3, .mpeg, etc...** please use `MediaPlayer` instead.

Thanks,

I hope this helps :)

Comment: SoundPlayer has to be outside the method as well, or stop will never work on the sound that's played on the first click, it will be an empty click, then will play a new version of the sound, and an musical round will ensue

Comment: @Wanabrutbeer You are right! I do not know how I did not notice this. Thank you for the information, I'll edit my code now :)

Comment: No worries! Also, you need to use PlaySync() if you aren't going to explicitly load the resource. If its a large resource I would consider explicitly loading, and use LoadAsync, and handle the LoadComplete event to start playback, and set the play state variable so stop will work on next click. Might also want to disable button on LoadAsync then reenable it and change text to "Stop" on the LoadComplete event. If you are new to asynchronous actions, now is a good time to brush up, they are quite useful, and indeed necessary on more complex applications

Answer (score 2):

EDIT - editing code fragment to show use of Asynchronous Load

Try this code:

```
private System.Media.SoundPlayer sound;
private bool isPlaying = false;
private System.Drawing.Image playimage = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(@"playimage");
private System.Drawing.Image stopimage = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(@"stopimage");

private void playstopbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (sender as Button);
    if (isPlaying)
    {
        sound.Stop();
        isPlaying = false;
        btn.Text = "Play";
        btn.Image = playimage;
    }
    else if (sound.IsLoadCompleted)
    {
        sound.Play();
        isPlaying = true;
        btn.Text = "Stop";
        btn.Image = stopimage;
    }
    else
    {
        btn.Enabled = false;
        if (sound == null) sound = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"wavefile");
        sound.LoadCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(sound_LoadCompleted);
        sound.LoadAsync();
    }
}

private void sound_LoadCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    this.playstopbutton.Text = "Stop";
    this.playstopbutton.Image = playimage;
    this.playstopbutton.Enabled = true;
    isPlaying = true;
    sound.Play();
}
```

The problem you might be running into is your scope for the sound is only inside the method, it needs to be class scope, so that the same instance sound is dealt with each time. Technically the int method you used shuold work if you declare the SoundPlayer outside the click handler. Also, whatever variable you use to track the play state needs to exist outside the handler method so that the value persists on each click action.